# Gradle: how to pass classes defined in script to JavaExec?

Tags: gradle

Gradle: how to pass classes defined in script to JavaExec? e.g.,

build.gradle

```
public class Foo {
   ...
}

javaexec {
    classpath ...
    main example.Executor
    args "fooClass", "Foo"
}
```

The class example.Executor needs to load the class Foo.class defined in build.gradle script. Is this possible?

How to add build script in the javaexec classpath?

Comment: Why would you want to pass a class in your build script to a `JavaExec` if you could just use its functionality directly?

Comment: The JavaExec has an interface that requires caller to provide an impl.

Comment: So the task is provided by a plugin and you want to pass a class that is not part of your application code but defined inside your build script? Could you add some context about the plugin and the actual use case?